# Force Spring JPA to insert Column with 'insertable = false'

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "sendingstate")
public class SendingState {

@Id
protected String sendingStateId;
protected String documentId;
protected String state;
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
protected Date createdAt;
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
protected Date updatedAt;

}
```

createdAt and updatedAt columns are auto filled by database it self, and its fine. But when i writing test - i want to be able to fill custom values in these fields so they can be saved in db. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Did you try it already? Show your code of the test.

Comment: You could have a copy of the class in the test section of the project that overrides it and has `insertable = true`, but then you'd have to list all the classes to scan in the persistence.xml, or suffer ClassLoader problems.